# SharePoint 2019 removes hash (#), anchor links from address - changes to question mark (?)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

SharePoint 2019

Three is a library with many documents. I'd like to use anchor links for automatic scrolling to a concrete document, for ex.:

https://sp-host/my-lib/Forms/AllItems.aspx#my-doc

I created these anchor links with the help of https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting. In library in document list I can see anchor links for each document in the corresponding field.

But the matter of fact is that SharePoint 2019 removes hash (#), anchor links from address and changes it to question mark (?) during my try to use an anchor link in browser address filed, for ex.:

https://sp-host/my-lib/Forms/AllItems.aspx?my-doc

After that automatic scrolling to a concrete document doesn't occur.

Please advise me how I can fix that? Why does SharePoint 2019 remove hash (#), anchor links from address and change it to question mark (?)? How can I adjust, setup SharePoint 2019?

I searched possible fixes in Internet but failed. I found that there exists a well-known corresponding issue for Angular with workaround as path handling should be changed - don't use hash (#) in paths. I also played with MDS feature (https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/02/disable-minimal-download-strategy-mds-in-sharepoint-2013.html) — but also failed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not a SharePoint basically it's IIS/aspx and then handlers and http modules. Because SharePoint basically it's a ASP.NET and they have in core standard iis life cycle and they have more handlers, httpModules. As far as I know # works correctly only for publishing stuff such us: Wiki, Publishing Pages. Because it's a content pages. The list pages and their displays work according to stricter rules, as in your example.
My suggestion : please try this case on content page for this are used Own handlers and modules etc.